# Fire Job only one time at specific date and time

Tags: c#, asp.net, quartz.net

I have that code for Job - just log info to database

```
 public class Job : IJob 
    { 
        private static readonly log4net.ILog log = 
log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod( ).DeclaringType); 
        #region IJob Members 
        public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context) 
        { 
            // This job simply prints out its job name and the 
            // date and time that it is running 
            JobKey jobKey = context.JobDetail.Key; 
            log.InfoFormat("SimpleJob says: {0} executing at {1}", 
jobKey, DateTime.Now.ToString("r")); 
        } 
        #endregion 
    }
```

My singleton scheduler class

```
public class Scheduler 
    { 
        static Scheduler() 
        { 
            NameValueCollection properties = new 
NameValueCollection(); 
            properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "myApp"; 
            properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = "MyApp"; 
            properties["quartz.threadPool.type"] = 
"Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz"; 
            properties["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "10"; 
            properties["quartz.threadPool.threadPriority"] = "Normal"; 
            properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = 
"TestScheduler"; 
            properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = 
"instance_one"; 
            properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = 
"Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz"; 
            properties["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "true"; 
            properties["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default"; 
            properties["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_"; 
            // if running MS SQL Server we need this 
            properties["quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type"] = 
"Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz"; 
            properties["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = 
"Server=localhost;Database=quartzr;Uid=user;Pwd=pass"; 
            properties["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = 
"SqlServer-20"; 
            _schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties); 
            _scheduler = _schedulerFactory.GetScheduler(); 
        } 
        public static IScheduler GetScheduler() 
        { 
            return _scheduler; 
        } 
        private static readonly ISchedulerFactory _schedulerFactory; 
        private static readonly IScheduler _scheduler; 
    }
```

Global.asax start scheduler

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 
            Scheduler.GetScheduler().Start(); 
        }
```

And code to add jobs

```
 DateTime SelectedDate = this.Calendar1.SelectedDate; 
                int hour = this.TimeSelector1.Hour; 
                int minute = this.TimeSelector1.Minute; 
                int second = this.TimeSelector1.Second; 
                // First we must get a reference to a scheduler 
                // jobs can be scheduled before sched.start() has been 
called 
                // get a "nice round" time a few seconds in the 
future... 
                DateTimeOffset startTime = DateBuilder.DateOf(hour, 
minute, second, SelectedDate.Day, SelectedDate.Month, 
SelectedDate.Year); 
                try 
                { 
                    // job1 will only fire once at date/time "ts" 
                    IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<Job>() 
                        .WithIdentity("job1", "group1") 
                        .Build(); 
                    ISimpleTrigger trigger = 
(ISimpleTrigger)TriggerBuilder.Create() 
                                                                  .WithIdentity("trigger1", 
"group1") 
                                                                  .StartAt(startTime) 
                                                                  .Build(); 
                    // schedule it to run! 
                    DateTimeOffset? ft = 
Scheduler.GetScheduler().ScheduleJob(job, trigger); 
                    log.Info(job.Key + 
                             " will run at: " + ft); 
                    this.Label1.Text = "Zdarzenie dodane"; 
                } 
                catch (Exception ex) 
                { 
                    log.Error(ex.Message, ex); 
                }
```

Problem is that jobs was add to db, but it fire immediately, not at 
specific time by me :/ I use latest library **Quartz.NET 2.0 beta 2**
Do I something wrong in code? I begginer with this API, please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quartz.Net expects that you pass in dates and times in UTC. Try changing this line:

```
.StartAt(startTime)
```

to

```
.StartAt(startTime.ToUniversalTime())
```

or, make sure that startTime is in UTC before passing it in.

Comment: How does this work with WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule passing DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder and StartingDailyAt?

Answer (score 1):

`StartAt` except `DateTimeOffest` ,  
Quartz has `DateBuilder` helper class for this

```
var minutesToFireDouble = (futureUTCtime - DateTime.UtcNow).TotalMinutes;
               var minutesToFire = (int)Math.Floor(minutesToFireDouble); // negative or zero value will set fire immediately
               var timeToFire = DateBuilder.FutureDate(minutesToFire, IntervalUnit.Minute);
               var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                           .WithIdentity("triggerC", "groupC")
                                           .StartAt(timeToFire)
                                           .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow())
                                           .Build();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do already know what UTC time you need your task to run at, you can do something like this:

UTC Start Time targeted:  Sept 1, 2017, at 12 noon

Set your Quartz "StartTime" as follows:

```
var MyTaskAbcStartTime = "2017-09-01 12:00:00Z"
.StartAt(MyTaskAbcStartTime)
```

Reference microsoft documentation for utc time format at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Hope this helps save some time for future Quartz users.